# Why is PyCharm not reconizing string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

[image]

PyCharm says the string is not recognized even though everything looks right to me.

Note: this is using PyCharm Community edition.

I tried editing it like deleting the string part so it would go through as valid syntax.

Comment: `=> String` isn't a python thing, where did you see that ?, same for the other lines, that's what is breaking everything

Comment: @azro  In a python course.

Comment: @Udaya2315 Either this is a very, very bad course or you have misunderstood something. I suspect the second alternative.

Answer (score -2):

Based on your screenshot, I assume you are using PyCharm virtual environment, to troubleshoot your problem I have listed some steps:

1. Left-click on project(above my-py-project) => select project files (this way you will only see your project files)
2. Delete the previous main.py, right-click on main.py => delete
3. create a new main file, right-click on my-py-project => New => Python File => main.py
4. Write this in main.py =>   `print("200 is a great number`
   , this should have solved your problem

**My suggestion**

From my personal experience,
I suggest you using the local interpreter instead of virtual environment, as you are quite new to PyCharm.

You can do this by selecting previously configured interpreter when creating a new project.

Comment: this is not helpful, OP's problem is the syntax, not the editor.